# Android Service Stops after a while

Tags: java, android, service, battery-saver, android-powermanager

my code runs at Android 5.1 (API level 22), in my application ondestroy activiit i will start my service for background works.
for a while everything goes normal and service is in running state. bu sudenly it stop.
whos can is prevent is from stoppng

`context.startService(new Intent(context, RunningService.class));`

` @Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}`
```

Comment: There is no way for prevent stopping.

Comment: You can create foreground service with startForeground and adding notification to it.